# Unable to show mCustomScrollBar on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, html, mcustomscrollbar

I have a div `<div id="MetricsTypeYearModelList"></div>` . In this div i am dynamically adding a ul element

```
$("#MetricsTypeYearModelList").append('<ul class="modal__list mCustomScrollbar" id="MetricsTypeYearModelListUl"></ul>');
```

After this i am looping over a JSON object and adding li element dynamically to the ul element

```
for (var i = 0; i < metricsTypeYearModel.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = metricsTypeYearModel[i];
        $("#MetricsTypeYearModelListUl").append('<li data-name='+obj.ModelTypeName+' data-value='+obj.ModelTypeID+' data-id='+obj.ModelTypeID+' class="pModel"><a href="#"> '+obj.ModelTypeName+'</a></li>');
    }
```

I have used "mCustomScrollbar" class in my ul element but this does not show up, normal scroll bar does show up. How can i show the CustomScrollBar

Comment: Note that when you append your `<ul>` elements, you add attach an *id* to it. You then go on to make another append logic on the same `<ul>` element going by *id* as your selector. Note that *id* is a *unique* selector. Therefore, your `$("#MetricsTypeYearModelListUl").append()` will only be applied to the first element it finds with the relevant *id*.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `live` configuration property to `true` in order to target elements that are dynamically added to the DOM.

So

```js
$(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({
    live:true // add this after your existing config options
});
```

---

Alternatively, and in this case might be a better option, just manually call `mCustomScrollbar` on the newly added element, after adding the contents to it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < metricsTypeYearModel.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = metricsTypeYearModel[i];
        $("#MetricsTypeYearModelListUl").append('<li data-name='+obj.ModelTypeName+' data-value='+obj.ModelTypeID+' data-id='+obj.ModelTypeID+' class="pModel"><a href="#"> '+obj.ModelTypeName+'</a></li>');
    }

$('#MetricsTypeYearModelListUl').mCustomScrollbar();
```

Comment: done with the second approach, thanks @Gabriele Petrioli